# Change Android's default focal-length

Tags: camera

I have Samsung device( GT-S7562) with 5 mp camera . When I updated it into CyanogenMod , I lost its camera quality . It always force me to take pictures with 3 mp . There is now option to change it . I tried lot of camera apps( including Google cam, HDR cam, Ported xperia,Samsung &HTC cams ...) and all those apps saying I have only 3 mp cam . So i think it is about the OS .

where can i change it ? I am happy if you prefer me to edit system files ;-)

Thank you

Comment: Which device specifically, CM version, no device tags? Please add this info as well here [edit] What other camera apps have your tried? What other apps that shows camera specs or system specs have your tried so far, do mention them?